# Can TFS and System Center Virtual Machine Manager share a SQL 2008 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, team-foundation-server, scvmm

I am planning on running on the same machine TFS 2010 Beta 1 and System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2 (on Windows Server 2008 R2).

Can they share a SQL Server or do they each need their own?  I am running SQL Server 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this with beta 2 of TFS 2010.  It all installed fine, but then I had issues with my collections not being seen.  I don't know if that is related or not.

Comment: Probably not related...and I don't see how this is an answer to the original question.

Comment: The original question was asking if TFS 2010 beta 1 could be on the same SQL Server as SCVMM.  Turned out I could not really try this out with beta 1.  I tried it with beta 2 and had problems that I did not have when I did not have SCVMM installed in the same SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why they couldn't share a SQL server. Most services like that create unique databases. I know for a fact that all of the TFS related databases (except sharepoint and reporting server) start with Tfs. So there should be no reason they can't co-exist.

Comment: Never really got to try as my SCVMM is on a Domain Controller and TFS can not be installed on a domain controller.